# PyInstaller bundle crashing on macOS 12 due to Python

Tags: pyinstaller, python-3.9, python-poetry, python-3.10, macos-monterey

We bundle a Python script and poetry environment into a PyInstaller macos bundle.

I bundled the app locally in my poetry environment which I work hard to keep clean and stable and then publish the output bundle to users via an S3 bucket.
My system setup

macOS 13.1

> poetry env info

```
Virtualenv
Python:         3.9.16
Implementation: CPython
Path:           /Users/ankurtoshniwal/pwr/thoughts/desktop_app/.venv
Executable:     /Users/ankurtoshniwal/pwr/thoughts/desktop_app/.venv/bin/python
Valid:          True

System
Platform:   darwin
OS:         posix
Python:     3.9.16
Path:       /usr/local/opt/python@3.9/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9
Executable: /usr/local/opt/python@3.9/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/bin/python3.9
```

Here's the PyInstaller spec file we've written to bundle the app:

```
a = Analysis(
    ['./ProjectWhiteRabbit.py'],
    pathex=[os.path.abspath(".")],
    datas=[
        ("./*.traineddata", "."),
        ("./gui/img", "./gui/img"),
        ("./gui/fonts", "./gui/fonts"),
        ("./alembic.ini", "."),
        ("./migrations", "./migrations"),
        ("./scripts", "./scripts"),
    ],
    hiddenimports=[
        "sqlalchemy.sql.default_comparator",
    ],
    hookspath=[
        os.path.join(community_hooks_path, "hooks/stdhooks")
    ],
    runtime_hooks=[],
    excludes=["tensorflow", "keras"],
    win_no_prefer_redirects=False,
    win_private_assemblies=False,
    cipher=block_cipher,
    noarchive=False
)

pyz = PYZ(
    a.pure,
    a.zipped_data,
    cipher=block_cipher
)

exe = EXE(
    pyz,
    a.scripts,
    [],
    exclude_binaries=True,
    name=__app_name__,
    debug=False,
    bootloader_ignore_signals=False,
    strip=False,
    upx=True,
    console=False
)

coll = COLLECT(
    exe,
    a.binaries,
    a.zipfiles,
    a.datas,
    strip=False,
    upx=True,
    upx_exclude=[],
    name=__app_name__
)

app = BUNDLE(
    coll,
    name=f'{__app_name__}.app',
    icon='ProjectWhiteRabbit.icns',
    bundle_identifier='builders.pwr',
    info_plist={
        "NSPrincipalClass": "NSApplication",
        "NSAppleScriptEnabled": False,
        'CFBundleName': __app_name__,
        'CFBundleDisplayName': __app_name__,
        'CFBundleVersion': __version__,
        'CFBundleShortVersionString': __version__,
        'CFBundleTypeIconFiles': ['ProjectWhiteRabbit.icns'],
        'NSHighResolutionCapable': True,
        # This makes the app appearance match the current theme in Mac
        # rather than always being light theme
        "NSRequiresAquaSystemAppearance": True,
        "NSAppleEventsUsageDescription": "Access to apple events allows PWR to be accessible through system wide shortcuts."
    }
)
```

#### Error:

A user on macOS 12.5.1 just reported getting this error when trying to run it:

```
[18060] Error loading Python lib '/Applications/Project White Rabbit.app/Contents/MacOS/Python': dlopen: dlopen(/Applications/Project White Rabbit.app/Contents/MacOS/Python, 0x000A): Symbol not found: (_mkfifoat)
  Referenced from: '/Applications/Project White Rabbit.app/Contents/MacOS/Python'
  Expected in: '/usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib'
logout
```

When I inspect the offending line:

```
> dyld_info  /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib
/usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib [x86_64h]:
    -platform:
        platform     minOS      sdk
           macOS     13.1      13.1
     MacCatalyst     16.1      16.1
    -segments:
```

The core concern is that the version of Python we bundled into the app is somehow not compatible with macOS 12.5.1 anymore. Everything was working fine in previous versions of the application, and there were some changes that were made to the poetry dependencies but the Python version was not changed.

#### I have two core questions:

1. If we didn't change the version of Python in our bundle, what else could have possibly changed in our bundle that caused this
2. Is there a way I can make sure poetry + PyInstaller uses a python distribution that is compatible with macOS 12+ instead of 13+

#### Findings:

I have noticed a minor discrepancy in the Python versions between my Poetry env and the final bundled version but it still doesn't explain the error. I use `pyenv` to manage my local versions of Python and here is what I noticed:

This checks out:

```
pyenv local
3.10.4
```

The python in the bundle:

```
> ./Project White Rabbit.app/Contents/MacOS/Python

Python 3.10.4 (main, May  2 2023, 15:32:58) [Clang 13.1.6 (clang-1316.0.21.2.5)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import syt
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'syt'
>>> import sys
>>> print(sys.version)
3.10.4 (main, May  2 2023, 15:32:58) [Clang 13.1.6 (clang-1316.0.21.2.5)]
```

My poetry env:

```
Virtualenv
Python:         3.9.16
Implementation: CPython
Path:           /Users/ankurtoshniwal/pwr/thoughts/desktop_app/.venv
Executable:     /Users/ankurtoshniwal/pwr/thoughts/desktop_app/.venv/bin/python
Valid:          True

System
Platform:   darwin
OS:         posix
Python:     3.9.16
Path:       /usr/local/opt/python@3.9/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9
Executable: /usr/local/opt/python@3.9/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/bin/python3.9
```

So the discrepancy of 3.9.16 => 3.10.4 between the poetry env and the final bundle. Again, to me this does not explain the error.

Happy to share additional details if needed!

Comment: it sounds like you accidentally compiled your project with a python version that was outside of your virtual environment.

Answer (score 0):

`pyenv` builds Python from source and doesn't set the `MACOSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET` (`-mmacosx-version-min` flag to clang) so `pyenv install $anything` will create a Python environment that cannot be ran on an older macOS versions than the one you just built on. Try:

```
MACOSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET=11.0 pyenv install 3.9.16
```

You should also check with `dyld_info` that each of your dependencies also use compatible macOS deployment targets.

Answer (score 0):

This cpython bug is relevant. However we are finding that even compiling 3.9.16 with pyenv for pyinstaller does not seem to fix the issue, despite the fix being in 3.9.16.

Prevent segfaults by adding macOS weaklinking for mkfifoat and mknodat system calls added in macOS 13 Ventura #97897

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).